# EmguCV implementation in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, opencv, xamarin.forms, emgucv, face-detection

I need to use the face detection feature provided by EmguCV on my Xamarin.Forms application. Does anyone know how to implement it?

Comment: Hi , if answer be helpful ,remember to mark it . Thanks in advance ^.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO ! Here is a Hello World to XamarinForms demo.

```
using System;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String win1 = "Test Window"; //The name of the window
            CvInvoke.NamedWindow(win1); //Create the window using the specific name

            Mat img = new Mat(200, 400, DepthType.Cv8U, 3); //Create a 3 channel image of 400x200
            img.SetTo(new Bgr(255, 0, 0).MCvScalar); // set it to Blue color

            //Draw "Hello, world." on the image using the specific font
            CvInvoke.PutText(
               img,
               "Hello, world",
               new System.Drawing.Point(10, 80),
               FontFace.HersheyComplex,
               1.0,
               new Bgr(0, 255, 0).MCvScalar);


            CvInvoke.Imshow(win1, img); //Show the image
            CvInvoke.WaitKey(0);  //Wait for the key pressing event
            CvInvoke.DestroyWindow(win1); //Destroy the window if key is pressed
        }
    }
}
```

You can refer to [GitHub project](https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/tree/master/Emgu.CV.Example/HelloWorld) and [Official document](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Tutorial) to modify code in your project .

==============================update==================================

If want to use EmguCV in Xamrin forms, you could install **Emgu.CV** nuget package in project. And refer to [this article](https://kampeki-factory.blogspot.com/2017/12/emgu-with-xamarin-forms-guide-part-1.html) to start.

[image]

Comment: Seems that from version 4.2.0 is packaged as .NET Standard 2.0 library. Do we know how to install and use it in a Xamarin.Forms app ?

Comment: @Milan You could install **Emgu.CV** nuget package in forms project to use. I have updated the answer. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Yep it is working. I voted for the response, but don't have that option ✔ in the upper left corner.

Comment: @Milan Glad it be helpful, and thanks for voting up. Later if could see the [✔](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7SAd.png), please accept that.

Comment: I added it, it compiles, but when I tried to used it in Pixel 2 Simulator I got an error: Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-acB7WQ051m8VOL7gfjjeNQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-acB7WQ051m8VOL7gfjjeNQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.a3mdinc.tmsmobile-acB7WQ051m8VOL7gfjjeNQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libcvextern.so"'

Comment: @Milan Hi, I have tested in local site and it works in android simulator. Do you mean when adding the nuget package and running in android device, it not works? If you have added some code of `Emgu.CV`, you could share them in question. I also will check that.

Comment: Yes, I added nuget package and runned into Android simulator and device and it gives me this message. I was following this tutorial: https://www.davidkaya.com/document-detection-using-emgucv/. It fails imidiatelly on the first line: var image = new Image<Bgr, byte>("C:/Projects/DocumentDetection/document.jpg");

Comment: @Milan Okey, the article used is `.NET Framework`, not `.NET Standard`. Therefore, it can not work. Maybe he installed is **EmguCV** nuget package, not **Emgu.CV** nuget package.

Comment: Yes, true that, but my project is using .NET standard library and Emgu.CV nuget package. On that line it fails with the message I posted (in runtime). Should we copy this libcvextern.so somewhere manually ?

Comment: @Milan Hi, there is [an article](https://kampeki-factory.blogspot.com/2017/12/emgu-with-xamarin-forms-guide-part-1.html) to expplain that using EmguCV in Xamarin Forms, you could have a look at that.

Comment: Yes, copying libs .so files and folder to the Android project, solved it.

Comment: @Milan Great! I have updated the answer. You could mark the answer when you have time , it will help others who have similar issue.